# Total views of any video not getting with facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to get total video view of Facebook public video. I have tried {post_id}/video_insights/total_video_views. But this is returning only data from my account.  I want to get total video views from any facebook account.  Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: No. If it is not your video, then this data is none of your business.

Comment: In my project there are two access level advertiser and publisher. Advertiser will add facebook url from their facebook account. and i want to display total views of that particular video to publisher. Is there any way to complete this functionality?